# How to remove the duplicate URLs from the XML sitemap in All in One SEO?

Tags: seo, wordpress, xml-sitemap, xml

I am using an All In One SEO plugin on my website. I am getting the duplicate links on my XML sitemap. The below is the screenshot. Is there any way to remove the duplicate URLs?

[image]

Comment: Maybe just use a better sitemap generator?   There is no shortage of sitemap generators for WordPress.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, All in One SEO generate the sitemap link called https://domain-name-change.co/page-sitemap.xml and there I am getting the duplicate link